# Browser-sync not reloading in gulp

Tags: javascript, gulp, browser-sync

I run gulp serve in the terminal, and the window pops up. But, when I make changes in the .html, those changes aren't reloading onto the page. I have no idea what async completion is, because this is my first time receiving this error.

```
[BS] Local URL: http://localhost:3000
[BS] External URL: http://10.0.0.58:3000
[BS] Serving files from: temp
[BS] Serving files from: dev
[BS] Serving files from: dev/html
^C[15:49:48] The following tasks did not complete: serve
[15:49:48] Did you forget to signal async completion?
```

```
let serve = () => {
    browserSync({
        notify: true,
        reloadDelay: 0, // A delay is sometimes helpful when reloading at the
        server: {       // end of a series of tasks.
            baseDir: [
                `temp`,
                `dev`,
                `dev/html`
            ]
        }
    });
    watch(`dev/html/**/*.html`, series(validateHTML)).on(`change`, reload);
    watch(`dev/js/*.js`, series(lintJS, compressJS)).on(`change`, reload);
    watch (`dev/css/**/*.css`, series(compressCSS)) .on(`change`, reload);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Gulp 4 requires each task to complete so it can continue to running the other tasks in the specified order (eg parallel or series).

You are getting that fatal error because your `serve` task is missing the `done` callback which lets gulp know you are ready to start the next task in the queue.

More info here: [What does Gulp "done" method do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29694425/what-does-gulp-done-method-do)

Below is an updated version of your `serve` task which will allow it to continue running concurrently without cause a fatal error.

```js
let serve = (done) => { // add done as an argument
    browserSync({
        notify: true,
        reloadDelay: 0, // A delay is sometimes helpful when reloading at the
        server: {       // end of a series of tasks.
            baseDir: [
                'temp',
                'dev',
                'dev/html'
            ]
        }
    });
    watch('dev/html/**/*.html', series(validateHTML)).on('change', reload);
    watch('dev/js/*.js', series(lintJS, compressJS)).on('change', reload);
    watch ('dev/css/**/*.css', series(compressCSS)) .on('change', reload);
    done();  // call the done method when you are ready to move onto the next task.
};
```